# Numerical Instability of C Loop

Tags: c, loops, physics

I am writing a piece of code to solve the LaPlacian at a boundary with charge density, in C. It uses the following loop:

```
chargeold[i] = charge[i];
charge[i] = -0.05*sgn(mat[i][j])*mat[i][j]*mat[i][j];
charge[i] = (1.0 - alpha)*charge[i] + alpha*chargeold[i];
mat[i][j] = (( mat[i][j-1] + di2*mat[i][j+1] ) / ( di2 + 1.0)) + 80.0*charge[i];
```

where the constant alpha is an under-relaxation parameter  0 < alpha < 1. This hasn't seemed to work and I think it may be to do with the numerical instability of the code - so far I have tried changing the constants, here -0.05, alpha and 80.0, and the sign in various the lines for calculating charge and mat[i][j] and get wildly different results depending on what I put: for example changing the coefficient of charge[i] on the last line by just 10.0 can cause the programme to get trapped inside a loop, diverge to infinity or -infinity, or quickly converge to 0 (which is not to be expected). This suggests to me a problem with the code I have created.

I have also tried condensing the calculation down into one line, or doing the same steps in different lines, and these also change the result wildy.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

n.b. all data types are double

EDIT - full loop looks like:

```
do
{
    sum_matdiff = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < meshno; i++)
    {

        for (j = 1; j < meshno; j++)
        {

            if (bound[i][j] == 1)   // holds boundary conditions
                continue;
            else
                matold[i][j] = mat[i][j];

            if ((i + j + count) % 2 == 1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (j == (int)(0.3 * meshno))
            {                   // if statement to calculate at boundary
                chargeold[i] = charge[i];
                charge[i] = -0.05 * sgn(mat[i][j]) * mat[i][j] * mat[i][j];
                charge[i] = (1.0 - alpha) * charge[i] + alpha * chargeold[i];
                mat[i][j] =
                    ((mat[i][j - 1] + di2 * mat[i][j + 1]) / (di2 + 1.0)) +
                    80.0 * charge[i];
                if (i == 50)
                {
                    printf("%f\n", charge[50]);
                }
            }
            else
            {                   // calculates outside boundary
                omega = 1.0 / (1.0 - 0.25 * omega * rho_sq);
                mat[i][j] =
                    0.25 * (mat[i + 1][j] + mat[i - 1][j] + mat[i][j + 1] +
                            mat[i][j - 1] + (mat[i + 1][j] - mat[i - 1][j]) / (2 * i));
            }
            mat[i][j] = (1.0 - omega) * matold[i][j] + omega * mat[i][j];
            sum_matdiff += fabs(1.0 - matold[i][j] / mat[i][j]);

        }

    }

    count += 1;
    av_diff = sum_matdiff / N;

}
while (av_diff > 0.01 || count < meshno * 2);
```

Comment: `for example changing the coefficient of charge[i] on the last line by just 10.0 can cause the programme to get trapped inside a loop` How the actual loop condition look like?

Comment: Where `count` is initalized?

Comment: In `j == (int)(0.3 * meshno)`, rather use `3*meshno\10` to avoid any issue with floating point calculation.

Comment: count is initialised a few lines above this loop

Comment: are you sure this is a code problem? some mathematical loops behave exactly as you described, a famous example is the mandelbrot set.

Comment: So this code looks good to me. Can you add an example of when this calculation fails to find the answer you expect? If you list all of your input values and your expected output, I could try it on my machine.

Comment: `charge[]` appears to have units the square of `mat[][]` in line `charge[i] = -0.05 * sgn(mat[i...`.  `charge[]` appears to have the _same_ units of `mat[][]` in `mat[i][j] = ((mat[i][j - 1] ...`.  Is this correct?